# How can adding two cells give a different result to adding the actual values?

Tags: excel

I presume this is a weird edge case but please could someone explain why it is happening?

So, I have two values (17145.08 & -14741.30), and I wish to add them together.
The result should be 2403.78.

If I type =17145.08-14741.30 into a cell, I get the correct answer, exactly 2403.78.

If I enter those values into two separate cells, and use a third cell to add (or SUM) those two cells, I get 2403.77999999999 (not visible without increasing the number of decimal places shown).

However, If I then go back to the first cell and re-enter the exact same value (17145.08), the sum recalculates to be correct.

[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Doesn't happen here (I'm in 64 bit Excel 16 ) What version are you running?

Comment: 32 bit Excel 16

Comment: I'd assume that it's an effect of how the machine stores negative decimals, except that it goes away when you re-renter the other value.

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)